# Post multiple text messages on Slack from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slack

I am using Slack Webhooks to post notification messages on Slack. It works well until I try to post more than one message on Slack in one request. It allows to post multiple images as attachments but it doesn't allow to post multiple messages at the same time.

It just overwrites the first message with new one, here is the code I am trying with:

```
return (new SlackMessage)
                ->success()
                ->content('Message 1')
                ->content('Message 2')
                ->attachment(function ($attachment) {
                    $attachment->image("Image url goes here");
                ->attachment(function ($attachment) {
                    $attachment->image("Image url goes here");
                               
                });
```

In the above code, I am trying to post 2 Messages and 2 Images. It successfully post 2 Images on Slack but just Post 1 Message i.e. Second one and overrides first one.

Comment: Are you wanting two distinct messages to come into Slack - as in two, completely separate messages?

Comment: No I want to post two messages in a single Slack Post... I know we can concatenate the String by applying Line Break, but I don't want to do that way.

What exactly I need.. I need to Post a Text then an Image then Another Text and then Another Image in the same Slack Post

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass your array in the attachment fields method or beak your text to multiple lines using [Markdown Attachment Content](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#markdown-attachment-content)

```
return (new SlackMessage)
        ->warning()
        ->attachment(function ($attachment) {
            $attachment->fields([
               'Title' => 'Server Expenses',
               'Amount' => '$1,234',
               'Via' => 'American Express',
               'Was Overdue' => ':-1:',
            ]);
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I managed to get the answer for this.

We can achieve this with the help of "Blocks" parameters in Slack. Since "Text" parameter allow only String value but "Blocks" allow bunch of Arrays to be posted there.

We can use it like follow:

```
$blocks = array("type"=>"section","text"=>array("type"=>"plain_text","text"=>"Message 1"));

return (new SlackMessage)
                ->success()
                ->blocks($blocks)    //here you can call it
                ->attachment(function ($attachment) {
                    $attachment->image("Image url goes here");
                ->attachment(function ($attachment) {
                    $attachment->image("Image url goes here");
                               
                });
```

Comment: I got this error, `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage::blocks() ` any solution?